prestashop cms - A large number of structural 404 errors: -large_default in google console
These 404 errors seem to exist  in PrestaShop 1.7.8.11 and panda template 2.8.6  sites have thousands of errors in Google Webmaster, which are with this link: example.com/2110-large_default/ Please guide me what is the problem?
prestashop image address
ex: image address: example.com/7245-large_default/%D9%86%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%B1-%D9%BE%D8%B1%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%85%D8%B1-%DA%A9%D9%88%D9%84-%D8%A2%DB%8C%D8%B3-20-%DB%8C%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%AF-coolice-2303.jpg
This full link is working

but this link example.com/7245-large_default/   http 404 error
How to fix this problem with htaccess or ...  to redirect to 404 page


Remove all modules installed in the last 3 months and retest
I deleted and recreated htaccess
Re-updating the template

